# Django Tutorial html css python for loop not working

Tags: python, html, css, django

I've come across this error in both djangogirls tutorial and the django tutorial from djangoproject.com  I am really trying to learn django, but I don't understand where things go wrong.

My html pages will no longer print out the for loops that loop through my choices in my poll.

Where the for loop should display the output, no data is displayed. The for loop is not being undertaken.

Here are my pages

polls\details.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
    {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

polls\index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}" />

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

polls\models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        # return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question) # each choice is related to a single question
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question) # each answer is related to a single question
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Choice) # each answer is related to the choices above # is this set up correctly?
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text
```

polls\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html' 
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5] 

     #def get_queryset(self):
     #       """Return the last five published questions."""
     #       return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

Comment: I don't understand why you've mentioned CSS here. What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: everything was working great until I added CSS

Answer (score 0):

Change choice to choices. Sometimes it may correct. Because these data is retrieving from a table in a database.